# Нужны ли кавычки в данном контексте?

Tags: пунктуация, числительные, кавычки

Первый случай. *Мужик долго тряс кости в ладонях, и когда, наконец, выбросил, толпа заулюлюкала. На столе лежали кубики с цифрами "пять" и "два".*

Второй случай. *Он сделал свой ход и когда его кубики закончили беглую пляску по грязной поверхности стола, все увидели "шесть" и "четыре".*

Третий случай. *Его руки дрожали, а на лице застыло выражение крайней сосредоточенности. Круглолицый бросил "пять" и "три". Увидев это, старик скривился от злости и впился взглядом в Лилит.*

(Текст взят из художественного произведения.)

Уместно ли здесь числительные давать цифрами?

Comment: На кубиках цифры, а не точки? По тексту - цифры, но не ошибка ли это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый случай отменяет кавычки: есть слово "цифры".

Если второй и третий ну ооочень далеко отстоят от первого, то кавычки на месте, а вот если в пределах одной страницы (не говорю уже: в одном абзаце), то **отменяем кавычки, подразумевая и наблюдая слово "цифры" из первого случая**.

В художественном произведении цифры отображаются разве что при диктовке адреса или телефона...

У А. Грина в "Крысолове":

> Итак, запишите, — не без лукавства сказала она это «запишите», —
>   запишите мой адрес: 5-я линия, 97, кв. 11.
>
> ---
>
> Впрочем, запишите наш телефон; может быть, я попрошу вас продать
>   книги.
>
> Я записал, с улыбкой поглядывая на ее указательный палец, которым,
>   сжав остальные в кулак, водила она по воздуху, ***учительским тоном
>   выговаривая цифру за цифрой***.
>
> ---
>
> Я бессмысленно твердил цифры, шевеля губами, чтобы нащупать их
>   достоверность Наконец мелькнул ряд, сродный впечатлению забытого
>   номера: 107-21. - "Сто семь двадцать один", - проговорил я,
>   прислушиваясь, но не знал точно, не ошибаюсь ли вновь.

Прочие цифры записывают словами.

---

---

***[Словами или цифрами?](http://esmira.net/uroki/urok-sedmoj.html)***

> **Правило 1.** В художественной литературе — только словами!
>
> **Правило 2.** В научных, деловых, рекламных текстах предпочтительна цифровая форма.
>
> НО!
>
> **Правило 3.** Различать однозначные и многозначные числа.
>
> В цифровой форме двузначные и многозначные числа схватываются
>   читателем быстрее. Они не переводятся мысленно в словесную форму, а
>   именно схватываются взглядом, что упрощает и ускоряет восприятие
>   текста.
>
> А вот однозначные числа в косвенных падежах в цифровой форме,
>   наоборот, усложняют чтение.
>
> Однако и однозначные числа (особенно в именительном падеже) иногда
>   предпочтительны, если нужно акцентировать внимание именно на цифре.

**Дополнение** (источник сомнителен для нашего случая):

***["Совпалыч". Виктор Солодчук](https://books.google.ru/books?id=rdG4AAAAQBAJ&pg=PT158&lpg=PT158&dq=%D0%9D%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%81%20%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%22%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%22%20%D0%B8%20%22%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%22&source=bl&ots=tTflRcFfRz&sig=mjV7JDEJ5PlenfdotPyHazuzyR4&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBhZuhx4TZAhVIDywKHatnCQIQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ой, перечитала! Везде же есть слово "цифры", кавычки отменяющие...

Но нашлось и иное, правда, литература переводная:

***["Желание неистового графа". Вики Дрейлинг](https://books.google.ru/books?id=GIsnCAAAQBAJ&pg=PT72&lpg=PT72&dq=%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%20%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C,%20%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=QWlDCCyD1G&sig=GPlAaLyjghFCvlLGd6ob580ZcGk&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirlpvSz4TZAhVH1ywKHerJC2kQ6AEIODAD#v=onepage&q&f=false)***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Ему выпало "шесть"!*** Без "числа" или "цифры"!

Comment: я знаю, что словами. как видите, там именно так и написано. Волнует только вопрос о кавычках.

Comment: Я дополню ответ найденным примером, но современная книга нам плохой указчик: разрушен институт корректуры-редактуры, ещё в 90-е.