# Пунктуация в предложениях

Tags: пунктуация, спп, запятые

Предложения взяты из данного вопроса: [Нужны ли кавычки в данном контексте?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437356/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5)

1. Мужик долго тряс кости в ладонях и когда, наконец, выбросил, толпа заулюлюкала. На столе лежали кубики с цифрами "пять" и "два".
2. Он сделал свой ход и когда его кубики закончили беглую пляску по грязной поверхности стола, все увидели "шесть" и "четыре".

Меня смутило, что автор вопроса указал на то, что эти предложения взяты из художественного произведения.
На мой взгляд, правильно такое оформление предложений:

1. Мужик долго тряс кости в ладонях, и, когда, наконец, выбросил, толпа заулюлюкала. На столе лежали кубики с цифрами "пять" и "два".
2. Он сделал свой ход, и, когда его кубики закончили беглую пляску по грязной поверхности стола, все увидели "шесть" и "четыре".

Прав ли я?

Answer (score 3):

Про кавычки всё собрано в указанном вопросе, а про знаки - это мы быстренько.

Надобно:

1. *Мужик долго тряс кости в ладонях, и, когда наконец выбросил, толпа заулюлюкала. На столе лежали кубики с цифрами "пять" и "два".*
2. *Он сделал свой ход, и, когда его кубики закончили беглую пляску по грязной поверхности стола, все увидели "шесть" и "четыре".*

ССП с двумя основами, осложнённое придаточным:

*когда наконец выбросил; когда его кубики закончили беглую пляску по грязной поверхности стола* - вот оне, придаточные-то.

Первая основа в ССП № 1: *мужик тряс кости*; вторая - *толпа заулюлюкала.*

Первая основа в ССП № 2: *он сделал ход*; вторая - *все увидели*.

Вы не правы с "наконцом" - это не тот случай, чтоб обособлять.

Comment: В справочниках указано, что в художественной литературе возможно выделение/невыделение слова наконец на усмотрение автора. Вот пример, когда наконец выделяется, несмотря на правила: И в таком положении молодые люди находились до конца августа, до того самого дня, когда,
наконец, Лапкин сделал Анне Семеновне предложение. А. Чехов, Злой мальчик.

Comment: У нас: долго тряс и наконец выбросил. Никакого повода для запятой. Вот было бы: *долго тряс, присматривался, принюхивался, головою непутевой покачивал и, наконец, выбросил,* - тогда да.